# Coefficients making expression independent of variables NOTE: updated

Tags: functions, trigonometry, summation

I have the following expression:

$f_S(\lambda,\tau,\beta)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1,\ \text{odd}}^{2S-1}\ \sum_{m,k=0}^{\infty}A_{nmk}(\beta,\tau)\tan^{2n}\big(\frac{\lambda}{2}\big)\tan^{m+k}\big(\frac{\tau}{2}\big)e^{\ i\ \beta(m-k)}\Big(\cos(\lambda)+\cos(\tau)\Big)^{4S}$

where $\lambda,\tau\in\{0,\pi\}$, $\ \beta\in\{0,2\pi\}$, $S$ is a positive integer or half-integer and $A_{nmk}$ doesn't depend on $\lambda$.

My question: Is there a way to make $f_S$ independent of $\tau$ and $\beta$ by manipulating the coefficients $A_{nmk}$ (i.e. by letting these have certain interconnections)?

I can't find a way, the problem being the last factor (one can get rid of the $\beta$-dependence by using the Kronecker delta: $A_{nmk}= B_{nm}\delta_{mk}$). Any ideas?

EDIT: I realized $A_{nmk}$ may depend on $\beta$ and $\tau$. Therefore, it boils down to:

$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}b_m(\tau)\tan^{2m}\big(\tau/2\big)\big(\cos(\lambda)+\cos(\tau)\big)^{4S}=g(\lambda)\ .$

My questions are then: is this possible, does the function $g(\lambda)$ have a unique form, and if so which?

Comment: I presume B is some coefficient that depends only on n and m, but what is delta?  It looks like it has a specific meaning, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: That's supposed to be the Kronecker delta; zero when $m\neq k$ and one when $m=k$. Thanks for the comment, I edited it in.